# Why do I get STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT instead of EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT when debugging 32 bit application on 64 machine?

Tags: c, windows, debugging, breakpoints

I am trying to write a simple debugger on Windows to debug 32-bit applications, my machine is 64-bits. I am using C language.

When I add breakpoint (`0xCC`) at the specified address, I expect to get `EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT` value in `debugEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode`

However I get `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT(0x4000001F)` instead.
MSDN website define it as *"An exception status code that is used by the Win32 x86 emulation subsystem."*. Without any further explanation for this behavior.

Can I handle this exception the same way as `EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT`? So the code will be as

```
switch(debugEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode)
{
...
   case EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT:
   case STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT:
      HandleBreakPoint();
   break;
...
}
```

Comment: also add about debugger (32/64 bit) difference. `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT` got only 64bit debugger, and based on this can say that you run 64bit code

Comment: For those coming from googling `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT = 0x4000001f`: the relevant MSDN docs are [MS-ERREF: 2.3.1 NTSTATUS Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55) and [Using NTSTATUS Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-ntstatus-values). They say: *“The NTSTATUS type is defined in Ntdef.h, and system-supplied status codes are defined in Ntstatus.h.”* For me, `#include "Ntstatus.h"` makes `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT` available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When breakpoint (`int 3`) exception was from code executed in WOW64 mode (32 bit code in 64 bit Windows) 64-bit debugger really got `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT`. When breakpoint from 64-bit code - `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` . Also on single step exception 64-bit debugger got `STATUS_SINGLE_STEP` if this exception from 64-bit code and `STATUS_WX86_SINGLE_STEP` if exception from WOW64 code.

> Can I handle this exception the same way as `EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT` ?, so
>   the code will be as

Yes, you can. Same is true for `STATUS_WX86_SINGLE_STEP` - you can handle it in the same way as `STATUS_SINGLE_STEP`. the `WX86_` gives you additional information from which mode (WOW64 or native) was breakpoint. But in both case this is breakpoint exception. And logic how handle it usually common. However this is your choice decide what do and how handle breakpoint, single step or other exception.

---

Also note that `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT` and `STATUS_WX86_SINGLE_STEP` got only 64bit debugger. 32-bit debugger always gets `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` where 64-bit debugger gets `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT` and nothing got where x64 debugger got `STATUS_BREAKPOINT`. The same for single step. For example on WOW64 process startup - 64-bit debugger got 2 breakpoints - first `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` form 64-bit mode (inside 64-bit `ntdll.LdrpDoDebugBreak`) and then `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT` from 32-bit `ntdll.LdrpDoDebugBreak`. While 32-bit debugger got only second breakpoint (from 32-bit code) with `STATUS_BREAKPOINT`.